# In neural network, how to force the NetTrain to use full batch gradient descent instead SGD?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

In a neural network, I want to use full batch gradient descent instead of SGD. Currently, I am using code like this (you can see that I forced `BatchSize` to be the number of data points):-

```
trained = NetTrain[net, associationInputToOutput, Method -> {"SGD", "LearningRate"->0.1}, BatchSize -> Length@trainingData]
```

However, I don't like the code, as it seems misleading to the others since there is the word `SGD` inside the code. Is there any other way to force the `NetTrain` to use full batch gradient descent?

Many thanks!!